# I installed openconnect on ubuntu 18.04 but sudo service openconnect status

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, openconnect

I installed `openconnect` on ubuntu 18.04 using `sudo apt-get install openconnect`. but when use `sudo service openconnect status` i get this error:

Unit openconnect.service could not be found.

I googled this problem but didn't fond any solution.

Answer (score 0):

The service file is `systemctl status ocserv`.

You may need to setup the VPN, refer to the links:
http://clusterfrak.com/sysops/app_installs/openvpn_install/

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openconnect-vpn-server-ocserv-ubuntu-20-04-lets-encrypt